# Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Using $this when not in object context in CodeIgniter

Tags: codeigniter

I'm writing a code using codeIgniter and this error appear.

PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Using $this when not in object context in C:\Users\Francis Myko\Downloads\Customer-Loan-Application-and-Management-System-master\application\views\loan\create_loan.php:2
Stack trace:
#0 {main}
thrown in C:\Users\Francis Myko\Downloads\Customer-Loan-Application-and-Management-System-master\application\views\loan\create_loan.php on line 2

This is my snippet from code:

```
<body class="">
    <?php $this->load->view('loading_screen');?>
    <div class="wrapper ">

        <!-- Top NavBar -->
        <?php $this->load->view('navigation/sidebar');?>
        <!-- End of NavBar -->

        <div class="main-panel">

        <!-- Navbar -->
        <?php $this->load->view('navigation/topbar');?>
        <!-- End Navbar -->
```

it works on my create_borrower file

```
<body class="">
  
    <?php $this->load->view('loading_screen');?>
    
    <div class="wrapper ">

    <!-- Top NavBar -->
    <?php $this->load->view('navigation/sidebar');?>
    <!-- End of NavBar -->

    <div class="main-panel">

    <!-- Navbar -->
    <?php $this->load->view('navigation/topbar');?>
    <!-- End Navbar -->
```

Please help badly needed. Thank you

Fix this code so i can finish my project.

Comment: what's the folder structure namely for ```create_loan```, ```create_borrower``` and ```loading_screen``` ?

Comment: create_borrower - Borrower Folder, create_loan - Loan Folder, loading_screen - Views

Comment: what does your controller look like when it loads `create_loan` view?

Comment: Well, when i don't fill in the whole form completely and submitting it, it still displays "Please fill in the form", but when i fill in all the fields i doesnt submit